# Encryption and Decryption between Java and Javascript won't work

Tags: javascript, java, encryption, cryptography, aes

**EDIT 1**

In the decryptFile method, the decrypt part will not output anything..

```
let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(e.target.result, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
    iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
    mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
    padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
});
```

**EDIT 2**
The [link](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) that has been given in the comments section partially solves the problem. It does encrypt and decrypt cross platform, but it is rather slow due to PBKDF2 with SHA256 hashing. I cannot find a way to only use the AES part and not the PKBDF2 part.

**ORIGINAL TEXT**

I am using the same key and IV for both the Java and Javascript version. I cannot decrypt a file in Javascript that has been encrypted in Java, nor can I decrypt a file in Java that has been encrypted in Javascript. I need those two to be compatible with eachother, but I cannot figure out how
I am trying to decrypt a file in Javascript that was previously encrypted in Java. I have succesfully implemented decrypting and encrypting text between the two, but when I would like to for example decrypt a file that is encrypted in Java, it just won't work.

Encrypt / decrypt a file in Java:

```
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

public class Test {
    private SecretKey secretKey;
    private IvParameterSpec ivParameterSpec;

    private String key = "ThisIsMyGreatKey";
    private byte[] ivKey = "ABCDEFGHabcdefgh".getBytes();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            new Test().run();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void run() {
        ivParameterSpec = new IvParameterSpec(ivKey);
        secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
        encryptOrDecryptFile(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE,
            new File("src/cactus.jpg"), new File("src/cactus-encrypted.jpg"));
    }

    private void encryptOrDecryptFile(int mode, File inputFile, File outputFile) {
        try {
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(mode, secretKey, ivParameterSpec);

            // Read input
            byte[] input = new byte[(int) inputFile.length()];
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
            inputStream.read(input);

            // Encrypt and write to output
            byte[] output = cipher.doFinal(input);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(outputFile);
            outputStream.write(output);

            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Encrypt / decrypt in Javascript

```
<input type="file" id="file-input" onchange="handleFile(this)">
<button onclick="useEncryptionForFile()" id="encrypt-file">Encrypt File</button>
<button onclick="useDecryptionForFile()" id="decrypt-file">Decrypt File</button>
<textarea id="output"></textarea>
<img id="example">

<script>
    let key = "ThisIsMyGreatKey";
    let iv = "ABCDEFGHabcdefgh";
    let useEncryption, useDecryption;

    let input = document.getElementById("file-input");
    let output = document.getElementById("output");
    let example = document.getElementById("example");

    function handleFile(element) {
        if (element.files && element.files[0]) {
            let file = element.files[0];
            if (useDecryption) {
                decryptFile(file);
            } else {
                encryptFile(file);
            }
        }
    }

    function encryptFile(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();

        reader.onload = function (e) {
            let encrypted = CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(e.target.result, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
                iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });

            output.textContent = encrypted;

            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute('href', 'data:application/octet-stream,' + encrypted);
            a.setAttribute('download', file.name + '.encrypted');
            a.click();
        };

        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }

    function decryptFile(file) {
        let reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function (e) {
            let decrypted = CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(e.target.result, CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(key), {
                iv: CryptoJS.enc.Utf8.parse(iv),
                mode: CryptoJS.mode.CBC,
                padding: CryptoJS.pad.Pkcs7
            });

             // Decrypted is emtpy    
            output.textContent = decrypted;

            // Desperate try to get something working
            example.src = "data:image/png;base64," + btoa(decrypted);

            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.setAttribute('href', decrypted);
            a.setAttribute('download', file.name.replace('encrypted', 'decrypted'));
            a.click();
        };

        reader.readAsText(file);
    }

    function useEncryptionForFile() {
        document.getElementById("encrypt-file").style.backgroundColor = "#757575";
        document.getElementById("decrypt-file").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        useEncryption = true;
      useDecryption = false;
    }

    function useDecryptionForFile() {
        document.getElementById("encrypt-file").style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        document.getElementById("decrypt-file").style.backgroundColor = "#757575";
        useDecryption = true;
      useEncryption = false;
    }
</script>
```

I also made a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/nvwc7rmr/8/) in case you'd like that more :), and the Java source can be [downloaded here](https://mega.nz/#!yDIEjKwI!tJ_taQxBiJevshxqeSeD2ANwJRvp-uFjFYQHVP3w1SM).

In the Java source I used a cactus.jpg as file, but any file could be used :). The cactus can be found [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kyBIc.jpg).

How can I decrypt the file that has been encrypted in Java? I have tried converting the blob contents to String, retrieving the data as ArrayBuffer and convert it to String, receive it as text and pass it to the decryption method, but nothing seems to work.

The library I am using in Javascript is [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js), and in Java the standard Crypto libraries.

I found other similar ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44469651/how-to-decrypt-a-file-in-javascript-which-is-encrypted-by-java-with-aes),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43518391/aes-javascript-encrypt-java-decrypt)) questions. However, I think they differ too much, as the answer of those questions does not concern this issue, but rather a small mistake.

If I've forgotten any data, please tell me.

Comment: Does the same encryption-decryption code work for simple text rather than a file? You can try something like Hello World.

Comment: It works for text

Comment: Honestly, if you "cannot find a way to only use the AES part and not the PKBDF2 part", then you should not be writing crypto code. At least not as anything other than a learning exercise, never to be used in production. Crypto simply isn't a field where you can just take some code you don't really understand and hack at it until it _seems to_ work. If you try, you're likely to end up with something that _looks_ OK at a glance but has holes big enough to drive an NSA surveillance van through.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that you interpret the decryption result as a UTF8 string.  That isn't how it works.  Files are just arbitrary bytes, they don't necessarily make up a UTF8 string.  The result of your decryption is correct if you just don't try to interpret it as UTF8.

Comment: That is the decrypt method for text, that one works. The one that is not working correctly is the decryptFile method, which uses Latin1

Comment: Doesn't really matter.  You can't give random binary data to a text encoder and hope that the data just happens to be in the right format.  It doesn't work like that.  Binary data is practically and semantically not a string.  The answer still applies.

Comment: The question still remains, how can I change the method in Javascript so I can decrypt it. Even if I change it from Latin1 to no encoding or whatsoever, it won't work

Comment: "It won't work" isn't a very helpful description of the problem.  Update your code in your question with the behavior you observe *after* removing anything to do with characters encodings from the output.

Comment: Your code *still* has `.toString()` on the end of it...  I really don't know how to be any clearer about this.  You can't convert binary data to a string...

Comment: Well the main concern is that with or without toString, there won't be any result.. I need it to be working, and I've already spent a lot of time trying to get it to work, so I therefore try every posibility but nothing works..

Comment: What behavior do you expect from the code?  Keeping in mind that JavaScript has only recently added support for `Uint8Array`.

Comment: The behaviour I would like to is that the file that is encrypted via Java can be decryped via Javascript and be downloaded. I have implemented the download part, but the decrypt parts seems to be not working.

Comment: "be not working" - **how?**  You need to be more descriptive.  What do you expect to happen and what actually happens?  Have you debugged at all?

Comment: "Be not working" as in: there is not result. If I upload the encrypted file and try to decrypt it, there won't be any result. let decrypted will just be empty. I expect it to return the bytes it contained originally (so when it was not encrypted). I have debugged a lot. I have tried passing blobs, passing array buffers, passing the file as text, but nothing seems to result in anything when decrypting. I have searched a lot but I just can't find the solution

Comment: If you could maybe point me in the right direction how I should be able to both encrypt and decrypt them cross platform, what I should tweak in order to get it working or anything

Comment: Look at the code examples [here](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples).  There is one for Java and for Web Crypto.

Answer (score 3):

Firstly, try sending simple encrypted text from java to javascript or vice versa and test if the code is working.

If the code is working for Simple text, i.e. , you are able to send a encrypted String from Java and successfully decrypt it in JavaScript or vice versa, then what you can do is Base64 encode the encrypted bytes/file and then transfer the text and then decode and decrypt it on other end.

If the code is not working for simple text, then you can try encrypting  a simple text in javascript and java independently and check if the result are same. If not, there is some mismatch in encryption/decryption logic between java and javascript.

**EDIT:**

As you mentioned that the code is working for String, I have show below an example to convert file into Base64 String using apache common codec library in java.

```
private static String encodeFileToBase64Binary(String fileName) throws IOException {
    File file = new File(fileName);
    byte[] encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file));
    return new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII);
}
```

Now you encrypt this String and send it to javascript. In javascript first decrypt the String and then convert it into a file object.

Eg.

```
 function base64toFile(encodedstring,filename,mimeType){
   return new File([encodedstring.arrayBuffer()],filename, {type:mimeType});

}   

//Usage example:
base64toFile('aGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=', 'hello.txt', 'text/plain');
```

Comment: Did you try my suggestion then?

Answer (score 2):

> The [link](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) that has been given in the comments section partially solves the problem. It does encrypt and decrypt cross platform, but it is rather slow due to PBKDF2 with SHA256 hashing. I cannot find a way to only use the AES part and not the PKBDF2 part.

The purpose of [PBKDF2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PBKDF2) is to turn a user-chosen password (which is typically a variable-length text string, and rarely has more than a few dozen bits of [effective entropy](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/374/how-should-i-calculate-the-entropy-of-a-password)*) into an AES key (which must be a binary string of exactly 128, 192 or 256 bits, depending on the AES variant used, and should effectively have full entropy** if you want the cipher to be as strong as it's meant to be).

To do that, it *needs* to be slow; the only way to make guessing a password with, say, 30 bits of entropy as hard as guessing an AES key with 128 bits of entropy would be to make the process of converting a password into a key take as much time as 2<sup>128 - 30</sup> = 2<sup>98</sup> AES encryptions.  Of course, that's not really possible, so in practice people tend to apply only a few thousand (≈ 2<sup>10</sup>) to a few billion (≈ 2<sup>30</sup>) PBKDF2 iterations and [hope that it's enough](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/69374/is-an-80-bit-password-good-enough-for-all-practical-purposes).  Which it might be, if your iteration count is closer to the upper end of the range, if the user is smart enough and motivated enough to pick a reasonably good password (say, a random [Diceware](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diceware) passphrase instead of `abc123` or `pa$$w0rd`) to begin with, and if your adversary is not the NSA.

Anyway, the point of all that is that, [if you want to use password-based encryption](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/45229/how-is-encryption-broken-today), then you pretty much *have to* use PBKDF2 (or [something](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrypt) [similar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon2)).  However, that does *not* necessarily mean that you have to run the slow key derivation function every time you encrypt or decrypt something.  In fact, if you know that you'll need to encrypt or decrypt multiple files with the same password, it's much more efficient to derive the AES key from the password once, and then store the AES key in memory for as long as you need it.  (Doing that securely [is not trivial, either](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1263350/cryptography-best-practices-for-keys-in-memory), but many crypto libraries will handle it at least reasonably well if you use their built-in key objects to store the keys, and in any case it's unlikely to be the weakest link in your application's security.)

The other option, of course, is not to use passwords at all, but simply to generate a (pseudo)random AES key (using a cryptographically secure random bit string generator) and store on all devices that need access to it.  Again, of course, the hard part here is securely storing the key.

In particular, if you're doing crypto on the client side with in-browser JavaScript, then simply embedding the key in the JS code (or anywhere else on the page) will expose it to anyone with access to the browser dev console (and may also result in the key being left lying e.g. in the browser's disk cache).  And of course you should be using HTTPS, since otherwise anyone e.g. eavesdropping on the client's public WiFi connection could also grab a copy of the key.

---

Ps. You might notice that I haven't actually included any code showing how to do plain AES encryption with PBKDF2 above.  I haven't done that for two reasons:

1. If you don't understand the crypto primitives you're working with well enough to, say, separate the key derivation from the encryption, then you really shouldn't be writing crypto code (as anything other than a toy exercise) anyway.

   That may sound harsh, but it's the reality — unlike many other subfields of programming, where you can just take a piece of code that you don't fully understand and tweak it until it works, with crypto (and with security-related code in general) you need to know what you're doing and do it right the first time.

   With other types of code, something that *seems to work most of the time* is often good enough, and you can fix any remaining bugs as they come up.  With crypto, buggy code can easily be completely insecure while *looking* like it's working perfectly, and you won't find out that it's broken until someone breaks it and steals all the data you worked so hard to keep secret.  Or possibly only long *after* that has already happened.
2. In any case, [the collection of code samples you linked to](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples) (<disclaimer>and which I have not reviewed in any detail</disclaimer>) *already includes* a set of methods that take binary AES keys and do *not* use PBKDF2.  Specifically, those are the `encrypt()` and `decrypt()` methods (as opposed to `encryptString()` and `decryptString()`, which do use PBKDF2).

   Note that, when calling `encrypt()` and/or `decrypt()`, you will need to provide the AES key in the format expected by the implementation.  In general, that may depend on the underlying crypto library used by the code.  [The Java implementation](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/blob/master/SCEE.java), for example, appears to be expecting a 128 / 8 = 16 element `byte[]` array.  (It would be kind of nice if it could also directly take a `SecretKeySpec` object, but it doesn't.)  The [JS WebCrypto implementation](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/blob/master/SCEE-Browser.js) seems to want a 16-byte [`Uint8Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Uint8Array) instead.  That's [apparently](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createcipheriv_algorithm_key_iv_options) fine for the [node.js implementation](https://github.com/luke-park/SecureCompatibleEncryptionExamples/blob/master/SCEE-Node.js) as well, although it can also accept a [`Buffer`](https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer).

---

<sup>*) That is to say, a decent password cracking program, based on in-depth knowledge of common human password-picking methods and habits, will rarely take more than a few billion (≈ 2<sup>30</sup>) or trillion (≈ 2<sup>40</sup>) attempts to guess most human-chosen passwords. In fact, depending on how lazy or inexperienced your users are, even just testing the few thousand [most common passwords](https://www.google.com/search?q=list+of+common+passwords) may be quite effective.</sup>

<sup>**) That is, guessing the key should not be easier than guessing a perfectly randomly chosen bitstring of the same length.</sup>